# Efficiently write millions of lines to a file using Python dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, file, dataframe

I have the following code snippet that reads a CSV into a dataframe, and writes out key-values pairs to a file in a Redis protocol-compliant fashion, i.e. `SET key1 value1`. The code is piecemeal and I have tried to use multiprocessing, though I am not sure of its performance (gains).

The CSV has about 6 million lines, that is read into a dataframe pretty quickly (under 2 minutes). The output file has 12 million lines (2 lines per line of the input file). This takes about 50 minutes to complete. Can any part of my code be optimized/changed to make this run faster? Once the file is complete, loading it to Redis takes less than 90 seconds. The bottleneck really is in writing to the file. I will have several such files to write and spending 50-60 minutes per file is really not ideal. This particular dataset has 6 million rows and 10 columns, mostly comprised of strings with a few float columns. The Redis keys are the strings and the float values are the Redis values in the key-value pair. Other datasets will be similarly sized, if not bigger (both with respect to rows and columns).

I was looking into loading all the strings I generate into a dataframe and then use the to_csv() function to dump it to a file, but I'm not sure of how its performance will be.

```
filepath = '/path/to/file.csv'

def df_to_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    f = open('output_file', 'w')
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if df['col1'].iloc[i] != '':
            key1 = str(df['col1'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1 = df['col_n+1'].iloc[i]

            key1a = str(df['col1'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1a = df['col_n+2'].iloc[i]

            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)

        if df['col2'].iloc[i] != '':
            key1 = str(df['col2'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1 = df['col_n+1'].iloc[i]

            key1a = str(df['col2'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1a = df['col_n+2'].iloc[i]

            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)
        if df['col3'].iloc[i] != '':
            key1 = str(df['col3'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1 = df['col_n+1'].iloc[i]

            key1a = str(df['col3'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1a = df['col_n+2'].iloc[i]

            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)
    f.close()

p = Process(target = df_to_file)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: Yes, don't use a loop, at least, don't use `iloc[i]` in a loop to extract a single row, this will *absolutely kill performance*. Unless you give a small representative example of your output data-frame, it's hard to say more

Comment: btw, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - there is no output data frame. The input is a data frame and the output is the file. The numbers mentioned here are real as well and not hypothesized or extrapolated. Using Python 2.7.

Comment: No, I meant *give an example of the data-frame that you are trying to output to a file*. I.e., what does `df` look like?

Comment: Can you show how you select `key1` and `val1` from DataFrame?

Comment: Also, where are all these variables: `key1, val1 = string1, string2` coming from? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a construction like `df['col1'].loc[...]` to loop over individual rows is going to be slow, the `iloc` and `loc` based selectors are for selecting *across entire data-frames*, and do a lot of stuff related to index-alignment that will have high overhead if done for each row. Instead, simply using `df.itertuples()` to iterate over rows will be *significantly faster*.

```
def df_to_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    f = open('output_file', 'wb') # writing in binary mode should be faster, if it is possible without unicode problems
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if row.col1:
            key1, val1 = string1, string2
            key1a, val1a = string1a, string2a
            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)
        if row.col2:
            key1, val1 = string1, string2
            key1a, val1a = string1a, string2a
            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)
        if row.col3:
            key1, val1 = string1, string2
            key1a, val1a = string1a, string2a
            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)
    f.close()
```

This is perhaps the bare-minimum optimization you could make. If you described in more detail exactly what you are doing, perhaps a vectorized solution could be found.

Also, don't use the above with `multiprocessing`.

Also, as written, `'SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a)` will always be the same. If those parameters aren't changing, then simply do the string concatenation *once* outside the loop and re-use the whole string in the loop.

Edit: Seems you can't do that above However, given:

> This particular dataset has 6 million rows and 10 columns, mostly comprised of strings with a few float columns. The Redis keys are the strings and the float values are the Redis values in the key-value pair.

Then simply `key1 = ''.join(row.col1, row.col4, row.col5, ...)` Don't use `str` and the `+` operator, this is horribly inefficient, doubly so since you imply those columns are already strings. If you *must* call `str` on all those columns, use `map(str, ...)`

Finally, if you really need to squeeze performance out, note that `row` will be `namedtuple` objects, which *are* tuples, and you cna use integer-based indexing instead of attribute-based label access, i.e. `row[1]` instead of `row.col1` (note, `row[0]` will be `row.index`, i.e. the index)` which should be faster (and it will make a difference since you are indexing into the tuple dozens of times per iterations and doing millions of iterations).

Comment: I just edited the question. Please take a look and update your answer (if needed). Thanks!

Comment: @CodingInCircles please provide a *concrete example*. Anyway, yes, your string-concatenation is horribly inefficient. Use `''.join` instead of `str(x) + str(y) + ... + str(z)`

Comment: Thank you! I will try the changes out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Wow! Your suggestions helped and it sped up exponentially! 12 million records written in under 1 minute! Thank you so much!

Comment: I asked the same question on Code Review SE, and thought I'd get an answer faster there, but I got it here instead. If you write this answer there, I can mark it as the accepted answer. Here's the link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187220/write-millions-of-lines-to-a-file-python-dataframes-and-redis.